# Django - place differently every second item in for loop

Tags: javascript, python, django, for-loop

Inside my well i have a list that splits to left and right. I want to place users in that list. I want to order them like: Firs one in the left list, second one in the right, third one in the left list, forth in the right... So every second user would be placed in the right list. Here is the html of the well:

```
<div class="well">
  <h4>Users</h4>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">User1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">User3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">User2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">User4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i cant do it just with classic for loop, because if i do as the below code shows, it would load the whole second list many times:

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">

            {% for user in users %}

            <li><a href="#"> {{ user }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">{{ user }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I would probably have to use `forloop.counter|divisibleby:3` but i dont know how to load just users in the second unordered list , without the whole list being copied for every user. Maybe soulution would use javascript too?
I hope you understand my problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other thing you can do to avoid sending 2 additional arrays is to use [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) in this manner.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         {% for user in users %}
            {% if not forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                <li><a href="#">{{ user }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
             {% for user in users %}
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                  <li><a href="#">{{ user }}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is great option as well!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I figured it out, after two days of trying it just came to me. If anybody is dealing with the same problem; I handled it in views:

```
def index(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    odd_users = users[::2]
    even_users = users[1::2]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'users': users, 'odd_users': odd_users, 'even_users': even_users})
```

And then i just loaded it in template:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         {% for user in odd_users %}
            <li><a href="#">{{ user }}</a>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
             {% for user in even_users %}
            <li><a href="#">{{ user }}</a>
            </li>
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Cheers!